# Animation loops even though i unticked the loop button

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am currently workin on my first project in unity...i dont have coding experience so thats why i am asking here for someone who could explain to me what im doing wrong here....Here is my script:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pre_behav : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject usoi;
    Animator anim;
    Animator fasol;
    float b = 0;
    float k = 0;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim=usoi.GetComponent<Animator>();
        fasol = this.GetComponent<Animator>(); 
        fasol.SetInteger("m", -1);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(anim.GetInteger("m"));
        if (b == 1 && anim.GetInteger("b") == 0)
        {

            Debug.Log("jumpscare");
            Invoke("jumpscare", 4);
        }
        else if(b==1 && anim.GetInteger("b") == 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("usa_inchisa");
            Invoke("al_ervedere",6);

        }
        else if (b == 0)
        {
            if (k == 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("apropiere");
                Invoke("goclose", Random.Range(10, 20));
                Debug.Log("a");
                k = 1;
           }
            else if (k == 1)
            {
                
            }
        
            }
    }
    private void goclose() {
        fasol.SetInteger("m", 0);
        b=1;
    }
    private void al_ervedere()
    {
        new WaitForSeconds(1);
        fasol.SetInteger("m", 3);
    }
    private void jumpscare()
    {
        new WaitForSeconds(1);
        fasol.SetInteger("m", 2);
    }

}
```

I am coding the bean and its goal is to jumpscare the player if the door is open...
here is how the program is running: https://youtu.be/WgVJvCrLhFI
and here is a link to some pictures of my animation transitions if it helps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9OyO.jpg
ok so b reffers the movement,if its 0(we havent moved yet) we play the animation in which we go to the door(this loops for some reason)....if b is 1 and the anim "b" is 0(the door is opened):the bean should jumpscare(it does)
if b is 1 and the anim "b" is 1(the door is closed) we play an animation in which we go back to the window(this doesnt work)
i though of bringing in a 'k' which would verify if we have played the animation in goclose but that doesnt work

Please any advice is welcomed and i beg you dont jump on me because my code isnt the best,please :)

Comment: So you test various conditions. Normally in an event such as this you unset the criteria so as to prevent reoccurrence

Comment: can you please give me an example?

Comment: @BugFinder is saying that you should prevent that condition from being immediately met again on the following frame.  eg. if `doUpdate == true` you typically set `doUpdate = false` to prevent firing the event again (without first setting `doUpdate = true` again somewhere).  Otherwise once your condition is met once, it is forever true unless something else changes those state variables.

Comment: You have no ideea how much you helped me,thank youu